# INADDR_LOOPBACK macro from <netinet/in.h> not imported in swift

Tags: ios, swift, macos, ipv4

I'm trying to use the peertalk framework which has no documentation.
On their obj-c example they use the INADDR_LOOPBACK macro, and example is working.
But when i try to do the same in swift the system throw me an unresolved identifier error.
Anyone knows how to fix it?

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Host-Address-Data-Type.html

Comment: I'd look in the source code, which you must have, see what this macro does, and translate it into the appropriate Swift code. The documentation says that it somehow represents 127.0.0.1. Translating C to Swift is fun. Swift 2 seems to be just slightly easier.

Comment: that's the thing, there is nothing in the source code which implies that the macro already exists inside obj-c
Saw what the macro is suppose to be but cannot put it in the variable that is accepted by the framework anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update for Swift 3:** As of Swift 3, `INADDR_LOOPBACK` 
is imported into Swift. Therefore it suffices to add

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
```

to the bridging header file, but a custom definition is not
needed anymore.

---

*Old answer:* For some reason, the macro definition

```
#define INADDR_LOOPBACK         (u_int32_t)0x7f000001
```

from `<netinet/in.h>` is *not* imported into Swift.
The problem *might* be the `(u_int32_t)` cast, because
other macros like

```
#define INADDR_NONE             0xffffffff              /* -1 return */
```

*are* imported.

One solution is to define

```
let INADDR_LOOPBACK = UInt32(0x7f000001)
```

in your Swift code. *Alternatively,* add

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
const uint32_t kInAddrLoopback = INADDR_LOOPBACK;
```

to the bridging header file and use `kInAddrLoopback` in the Swift code.
This is less error-prone because you don't have to repeat the constant.

Comment: @thibautnoah: You are welcome! (I have added another possible solution :)

Comment: appreciate it, indeed it is more efficient that way

Answer (score 0):

From the Apple documentation.

> Declare simple macros as global constants, and translate complex
>   macros into functions.

Comment: I don't think you understand my question