# How to bridge a long long C macro to Swift?

Tags: c, swift, macros, swift2, long-long

In Foundation there is C macro `NSURLResponseUnknownLength` defined as a `long long`:

```
#define NSURLResponseUnknownLength ((long long)-1)
```

Due to the way macros are bridged to Swift, this constant is accessible in an Objective-C application, but not in a Swift application.  How can I make macros like these visible to Swift?

I've tried wrapping the macro in a global C function in my bridging header:

```
long long getNSURLResponseUnknownLength() {
    return NSURLResponseUnknownLength;
}
```

But accessing `getNSURLResponseUnknownLength()` causes the `Undefined symbols for architecture` build error.

Comment: Your wrapping solution works for me (tested with Xcode 8 beta 6). `print(getNSURLResponseUnknownLength())` compiles, runs, and prints `-1`.

Comment: @MartinR interesting, does not work with Xcode 7.3.1 for me.  Maybe I was doing something wrong somewhere?

Comment: Btw, here is a similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34042017/macro-is-working-in-objective-c-but-not-it-swift with the same solution :)

Comment: @MartinR You have seen it all when it comes to Swift!

Comment: Btw, you can make it work in Xcode 7.3.1 with `static long long getNSURLResponseUnknownLength() { ...}`. But of course defining a constant is nicer.

Comment: Nice find, thanks @MartinR!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to declare a new constant value from the macro:

```
const long long myNSURLResponseUnknownLength = NSURLResponseUnknownLength;
```

This bridges `NSURLResponseUnknownLength` as an `Int64` `let` constant.

Usage:

```
if urlResponse.expectedContentLength == myNSURLResponseUnknownLength {
    // ...
}
```

Martin R mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39256489/how-to-bridge-a-long-long-c-macro-to-swift?noredirect=1#comment65849901_39256489) that the attempt in the question works on Xcode 8.  In Xcode 7, you need to declare the function as `static`:

```
static long long getNSURLResponseUnknownLength() { /* */ }
```

This is a known issue with Swift and will hopefully be fixed in an upcoming release.

- [SR-485](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-485)
- `rdar://problem/20462344`